# highlighted region in 2d line plot

Tags: matlab, plot

The code below highlights certain regions of a plot:

```
x = 1:24;
a = 1;
b = 50;
y = a + (b-1).*rand(length(x),1);

plot(x,y);

%find the peaks in the data and hilghlight the regions
[pks,locs] = findpeaks(y);

for i = 1:length(locs);
    h = area([locs(i)-(locs(i)/100) locs(i)+(locs(i)/100)],[max(y) max(y)]);
    set(h,'FaceColor',[.5,.5,.5]);
    set(h,'EdgeColor',[.5,.5,.5]);
    h1 = get(h,'children');
    set(h1,'FaceAlpha',0.3);
    hold on
end
    plot(x,y,'k');
    hold off;
    axis([min(x) max(x) min(y) max(y)]);
```

The area highlighted is defined as 1% of the length of the data either side of the local maxima. I would like to alter so that the region is not precisely specified by a percentage of the data, as this will alter depending on the size of the data set. Can anyone suggest an alternative method for defining the thickness of the highlighted region?

Comment: Did my answer below solve your problem/question? The etiquette here is that when you post a question you atleast follow it up :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that such a parameter should be considered a constant in the same way you consider `x`, `a`, and `b` to be constants.

I would define a constant width `w` of the highlighted region:

```
w = 1.0;
```

Then the line of code drawing the area will be w/2 on each side of the current peak:

```
h = area( ...
   [locs(i)-(w/2) locs(i)+(w/2)], ...
   [max(y) max(y)] ...
);
```

Adjust `w` so that it fits your current needs.

Comment: To be honest I was looking for a more sophisticated answer than simply using +-1 on either side of the peak.

Comment: Well ... I did not know that :) What is sophisticated? The most simple solution is always the best. You have not defined what kind of data you would like to plot. And that's why I just set a manual margin. You, as the designer of your plot, decide the width of the highlight. You could go "sophisticated" and use `w = pi;`. Or even `w = 1.066`; Would that solve it for you?